# Why doesn't this array become zero?

Tags: c++, arrays

I have written this piece of code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double function(int i)
{
    static int Array[5] = {0};

    for(int j = i ; j <= i ; j++)
    {
        Array[j+1] = Array[j]+1;
    }
    return Array[i+1];
}

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= 4 ; i++)
    {
        cout << function(i) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which outputs `1,2,3,4,5`

I am wondering why elements of Array at each call of `function(i)` doesn't become zero despite this piece of code :

```
static int Array[5] = {0};
```

Comment: Because that's the whole point of declaring the variable `static`. In fact this program looks like it's written to demonstrate exactly this fact. So either 1. you got it from an external source that should also explain the reason for this behaviour, or 2. **you** wrote it to test the behaviour of `static`, in which case you should already have a clue about the answer, or 3. it is homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array is `static`, which means it gets initialized just once (the first time `function` is called). It keeps its existing items thereafter. If you remove the `static` keyword you will get 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 instead.

By the way, the `for` loop inside `function` is redundant (it's guaranteed to only execute exactly once).

Answer (score 3):

When you use `static` keyword for declaring a variable inside a function. Then:

- The variable is created when the function is called first time.
- Thereafter the variable remains alive throughout the lifetime of the program &
- The value of the variable persists between function calls.

What you observe is this property of the keyword `static` at work.

Answer (score 1):

The `Array` is `statics`. `static` variables only initialize **once**. Therefor, `Array` becomes zero only on the first call.

if you remove the `static` keyword it will become zero on every call.

by the way the following code is very strange:

```
for(int j = i; j <=i ; j++)
```

because it only runs for `j=i`. So you can change the whole function by the following:

```
double function(int i)
{
    static int Array[5] = {0};
    Array[i+1] = Array[i]+1;
    return Array[i+1];
}
```